# Bind List<KeyValuePair> to combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, keyvaluepair

I cannot create a class or my own object so I thought I would use a `List<KeyValuePair>` to store two properties and then bind this object to a combobox.

However, I cannot see how I can set the `valueField` and `TextField` in the combobox.

The code.

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> kvpObject = 
 new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();

foreach (User u in m_users) {

    kvpObject.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(u.ID, u.Name));
}

// Bind Add Users combobox
cmboBox.DataSource = kvpObject;
cmboBox.ValueField = "????" // Maybe something like kvpObject[0]..
cmboBox.TextField  = "????";
cmboBox.DataBind();
```

Does anyone know what I need to put inside the `????`.

Comment: ValueField = "Key" TextField = "Value" ?

Comment: Really? wow...Cheers

Comment: Would depend on what you are trying to achieve though

Comment: So basically for each item in the datasource, there is its Key (u.ID) and its value (u.Name)

Comment: If you want cmboBox.SelectedValue to be the ID set its ValueField to the Key... you should also consider to make an Dictionary<int,string> instead of your List<KeyValuePair<int,string>>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think it should be like this:

```
cmboBox.ValueField = "Key";
cmboBox.TextField  = "Value";
```

Because you are using the KeyValuePair. The properties is `Key` and `Value`

**Update:**

I also have a suggestion. Instead of using a for loop. Then you can use Linq to bind it to the datasource of the combobox. Something like this:

```
cmboBox.DataSource = m_users
                      .Select (s =>new KeyValuePair<int,string>(s.ID,s.Name))
                      .ToList();
cmboBox.ValueField = "Key";
cmboBox.TextField  = "Value";
cmboBox.DataBind();
```

Remember to include `System.Linq;`

Comment: Wow, pretty simple. WIll give it a bash. thanks! (will mark when SO lets me)

Comment: @user3428422 : I update the answer with a suggestion as well. Have a look

Comment: Yeah the suggestion is very good, I do like using LINQ. I would recommend this way. Thanks again

Comment: How can i use it with foreach?